# allocate to Variables

Tags: numbering, external-files

I want to use the numbers in Blues.tex, but the number are real number like 234.65 but \setcounter can just use integer like 234.
But this is not possible by using \setcounter.
I Want to use many txt data and sum them all in one .tex document.
So I don't how to allocate to Variables. The solution I found is this:

```
\newread\NoFile 

\newcounter{Blues}

\openin\NoFile=V/Blues.txt%

\read\NoFile to \fileline

\setcounter{Blues}{\fileline}

\closein\NoFile
```

Thank you for your support

Comment: don't use a counter use a macro so `\read\NoFile to \Blues`

Comment: Thank you that helps me